# Notify pip to use already installed requirements, when I install a new package in a different directory

Tags: python, installation, pip

When I install a new Python package `AAA` **with `-t` option** : command like `python3 -m pip install AAA -t .`

It **also re-installs** basic requirements ( like `numpy` ) which are already in `site-packages`. So it makes **a duplicate.**

I want to **make pip use already installed requirements in `site-packages`** so that not to make a duplicate.

How can I do?

Comment: `-t` is a target flag, are you not providing a target path?

Comment: @PApostol No, as you see I used current path as a target path. And I tried `--target` too but same.

Comment: I believe pip only looks at existing dependencies that are in the same directory as the one you want to install your package in. Hence why it re-installs some packages. I'm not sure if there's a way around this but I'd also like to know.